# Take last 3 records from child. Php/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Help me please.

I'm trying to write a function where I get all the categories of my forum with the 3 most recently updated Topics in the given categories.

But according to the result, take(3) filters by id (where the id is not higher than 3), and I need to get the last 3 records.

```
public function index()
{
    $forums = Category::with(['posts' => function ($q){
    return $q->take(3)->get();
}])->get();
dd($forums);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can not use take() or limit() inside with();

---

EDIT: solution that was selected by mr.Sardov is to use package staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit.
Link is provided below this answer.

---

So for you need to do is by limit it from model relationship.

For example:

```
class Category extends Model {

public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post');
}

public function limitPosts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post')
      ->limit(3);
}

public function limitLatestPosts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post')
      ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc'). // or use ->latest()
      ->limit(3);
}


}
```

And that use it like this:

```
Category::query()
->with(['limitPosts' => function($query) { 
   $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc'); // the last records
}])
->where('id', '<=', 3) // id not higher than 3
->get();
```

Or

```
Category::query()
->with('limitLatestPosts')
->where('id', '<=', 3) // id not higher than 3
->get();
```

Hope this can help you out.

Comment: another solution is to use this package https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit , with this you can use limit inside `->with(['posts' => function .... ]`

Comment: Your first solution didn't work, but eloquent-eager-limit seems working. Thank you very much, man! You saved my day.

And I am only learning laravel, so I want to ask, is it okay to use extensions at all, or it is not recommended?

Thank you once more.

Comment: glad the Staudenmeir package can help you out. What do you mean by extensions? You mean 3rd party packages. Sure you can always add some, like `spatie/laravel-permissions` or `nwidart/laravel-modules` ...  but as always more code might slow your project down , add them as you need really2 need them, otherwise code it yourself

Answer (score 1):

you should order your complete query by update_at descending, only after you can take the first 3.

```
$q->orderBy('update_at', 'desc')->take(3)->get();
```

Your Categories table seems to be a different table from posts, so when a post is created or updated you should also set update_at of its category to now.

Comment: Thanks for response. Tried this already. Same result :(